# Is there an easy way to merge objects and sum their int properties instead of overriding in javascript es2018?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Alright, so this is what I have in mind.

I have two example objects

```
let obj1 = { x: 60 };

let obj2 = { x: 9 };
```

I want to merge these objects in a way that their integer properties will combine as well, and not override each other, so the end result will be

```
let obj3 = { x: 69 };
```

So I've looked into Object.assign, but this function only merges properties in a way that it favors the properties on the first object if the other objects have a property with the same name, and doesn't sum integer properties.

I can, of course, just make a function that loops over each object's properties and creates a new object with the summed properties, but that'd be longer and I wanted to know if there's already a function that does it easily like the way Object.assign acts.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no built-in facility to do that.

Comment: This is not the definition of merging, what your looking at is more summing

Comment: @CharybdeBE I know that, that's what I eventually said in the question. What is the most efficient way to do it, then? Or is there no other way than just looping and looping.

Comment: Yes, you won't get around looping (and notice that `Object.assign` isn't more efficient than looping, it's just syntactic sugar). Of course you can write some helper functions that will fit your need with the same ease of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Lodash` library you could do this with `mergeWith` method.

```js
let obj1 = { x: 60, b: "foo", c: {y: 3, x: 'bar'} };
let obj2 = { x: 9, a: 'bar', c: {y: 4} };

const sum = _.mergeWith(obj1, obj2, (a, b) => {
  if (_.every([a, b], _.isNumber)) return a + b;
})

console.log(sum)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also test other for other types https://jsfiddle.net/j8sbw7zy/1/ and do something else

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the objects by taking an arbitrary count of objects and reduce the key/value pairs by respecting nested objects.

```js
const
    add = (...a) => a                         // take all parameters
        .map(Object.entries)                  // get entries
        .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], [])   // flat entries
        .reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
            o[k] = v && typeof v === 'object' // assign if object
                ? add(o[k] || {}, v)          //   result of recursive call
                : (o[k] || 0) + v;            //   or sum the value
            return o;
        }, {});

let obj1 = { x: 60, y: { z: 3 } },
    obj2 = { x: 9, y: { z: 1, a: 32 } },
    obj3 = { y: { a: 10 } },
    result = add(obj1, obj2, obj3);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great answer as always, but I think people would appreciate comments and/or more explicit variable names

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
let obj1 = { x: 60 };
let obj2 = { x: 9 };

let obj3 = [obj1, obj2].reduce((s,a)=>{return {x: s.x+a.x}}, {x:0});
 
console.log(obj3);

// or more shortener:

obj3 = {x:[obj1, obj2].reduce((s,a)=> s + a.x,0)};

console.log(obj3);

// for arbitrary properties, not just x:

keys = Object.keys(obj1),
obj3 = [obj1, obj2].reduce(function (r, o) {
    keys.forEach(function (k) {
        r[k] += o[k];
    });
    return r;
}, keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
    r[k] = 0;
    return r;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: I guess OP is looking to do this for arbitrary properties, not just `x`.

Comment: This answers the question properly, but fails to go further like in Nenad Vracar's answer. This doesn't work on objects like `{foo: 10, bar: 'baz'}` or `{foo: {bar: 10}}`

Comment: Bergi, ok. I fix.

Comment: I haven't commented at first since your code was only for one value, and the code after the edit for arbitrary properties is not really an answer since I was looking for an easy, short way. Otherwise I can just make the function on my own... but thanks for the effort.